# Give app resource priority?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, ram, resource-monitoring

I have a couple apps I use regularly that take a *lot* of resources, the biggest hog is Vainglory which being essentially a desktop-class game uses most of the ram, CPU power and network bandwidth my Galaxy S5 has to offer when running.

It works fine most of the time, but occasionally while I am playing, the operating system or other apps will start doing things in the background causing my framerate and ping to drop dramatically.  Also when the app looses focus, even for just a second, it has to reload completely due to the large amount of memory it requires.

Is there a way to tell Andriod to give high resource priority to particular apps and prevent other applications and processes from working in the background while those apps are running?

Comment: Maybe by  killing all running apps when this application is launched. Would require root privileges to do that. Is your device rooted ?

Comment: If not rooted, try this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.piebridge.brevent

Comment: To kill is always last resort (or punishment). Leave that to executioners when possible :) Meanwhile, take a look at [Keeping important apps alive even on overheat](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/69744/16575) // [Keeping an app in memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28220/16575) // [How to lower OOM value of an app permanently?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/23469/16575)